# SetState only update on second click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, promise

I saw that this question has already been asked before, but without a suitable answer,
I am trying to do refactoring from CLASS COMPONENT to FUNCTION COMPONENT,
In the code of the CLASS everything works fine,
But when I change it to FUNCTION COMPONENT the STATE is only updated on the second click, and I get an error of

**Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startTimestamp')**

Previous code:

```
                       onClick={() => {
                      this.canvas.current
                        .exportImage("png")
                        .then((data) => {
                          this.setState({ img_base64: data });
                        })
                        .then((data) => {
                          //date
                          this.setState({
                            date: Date.now(),
                          });
                        })
                        .then((data) => {
                          //path
                          this.canvas.current.exportPaths().then((data) => {
                            this.setState({ path: data });
                          });
                        })
                        .then(() => {
                          this.setState({ count_path: this.state.path.length });
                        })
                        .then(() => {
                          //time
                          this.canvas.current
                            .getSketchingTime()
                            .then((data) => {
                              const first = this.state.path[0].startTimestamp;
                              const last =
                                this.state.path.slice(-1)[0].endTimestamp;

                              this.setState({ sketchTime: last - first });
                            });
                        })
                        .then(() => {
                          //time from start to first draw
                          const first = this.state.path[0].startTimestamp;
                          this.setState({ startTime: first - this.state.now });
                        })
                        .then(() => {
                          this.submitTest();
                        });
                    }}
```

My attempt of code:

```
                   onClick={() => {
                    canvas.current
                      .exportImage("png")
                      .then((data) => {
                        setImg_base64(data);
                      })
                      .then((data) => {
                        //date
                        setDate(Date.now());
                      })
                      .then((data) => {
                        //path
                        canvas.current.exportPaths().then((data) => {
                          setPath(data);
                        });
                      })
                      .then(() => {
                        setCount_path(path.length);
                      })
                      .then(() => {
                        //time
                        canvas.current.getSketchingTime().then((data) => {
                          const first = path[0].startTimestamp;
                          const last = path.slice(-1)[0].endTimestamp;
                          setSketchTime(last - first);
                        });
                      })
                      .then(() => {
                        //time from start to first draw
                        const first = path[0].startTimestamp;
                        setStartTime(first - now);
                      })
                      .then(() => {
                        submitTest();
                      });
                  }}
```

I understand that the code is not written correctly, and I tried to do it with ASYNC AWAIT as well
But without success, when I print the SATATE I don't see anything, only on the second click it shows the data,

Would appreciate help

Comment: state updates are async, that means they are available ready for the next render ... so you wouldn't have the state value from state ready for your next operations immediately after setting state

Comment: thx I know this, I dont know how to fix it :)

Comment: every time you used value set to state, I guess you already have `data` make use of it instead of getting same value from `state` that is just set

Comment: use useEffect to check when state update

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you need all these `then` but what you should do is return in every `then` the original `data` and then handle it accordingly with your hook setters.

So, instead of referencing your local state variable `path` which probably isn't set yet, you will use the returned `data` value inside your setters.

```
           onClick={() => {
            canvas.current
              .exportImage("png")
              .then((data) => {
                setImg_base64(data);
              })
              .then((data) => {
                //date
                setDate(Date.now());
              })
              .then((data) => {
                //path
                canvas.current.exportPaths().then((data) => {
                  setPath(data);
                });
                
                return data;
              })
              .then((data) => {
                setCount_path(data.length);
                return data;
              })
              .then((dat) => {
                //time
                canvas.current.getSketchingTime().then((data) => {
                  const first = dat[0].startTimestamp;
                  const last = dat.slice(-1)[0].endTimestamp;
                  setSketchTime(last - first);
                });
                
                return dat;
              })
              .then((dat) => {
                //time from start to first draw
                const first = dat[0].startTimestamp;
                setStartTime(first - now);
              })
              .then(() => {
                submitTest();
              });
          }}
```

Comment: hey, I tried it

Still returns the same error, and only works on the second click

Comment: at which line is the error thrown?